# I want to store the email as well as send the email to the user at the same time in laravel. how to store the data as well in the same time?

Tags: laravel

```
$data= Input::except('_token');
if($data) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('email.sendemail', ['data' => $data], function ($m)
    {

        $m->from(config('app.email') );

        $m->to( 'dsh@fads.com')
            ->subject('Ete');

        Session::flash('flash_success', 'Email sent Successfully!');
    });
}

else
{
    Session::flash('flash_warning', 'Error in process!!');
}
return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use Laravel Mail events to capture any kind of data in database. It would be the common place to all mails. Also it ensure you to trigger when mail is in `sending` state or `sent`.

Here is the example to capture data on email sent.

## 1. Create a Listener class with name `CaptureMailData` Like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent;

class CaptureMailData
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSent $event)
    {
        // Log the message
        Log::info($event->message);

        // Add your save functionality here.
    }
}
```

## 2. Register Listener for receive mail event.

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\CaptureMailData'
    ]
];
```

---

## Sending Additional Data:

If you would like to send additiona data to capture. You can use `withSwiftMessage()` to set the additional data with message attribute. Like:

```
$user = User::first(); //any kind of data.

$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($user) {
        $message->user = $user;
});
```

And can access the additional data inside `CaptureMailData` listener as:

```
public function handle(MessageSending $mailEvent)
{
    $user = $mailEvent->message->user;

    Log::info($user); // just to log.
}
```

Here is the link for sending additional data:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/accessing-the-mailable-properties-from-the-messagesending-event-that-is-triggered-when-sending-mail-through-the-mail-facade

Answer (score 0):

check out this [how to send email in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476577/how-send-email-in-laravel-5-8/56477002#56477002)

it could be of help to you. secondly, to save the email in the database, try this:

```
public function SendMail(Request $request)
{
    $email=$request->input('email');
    DB::table('table')->insert([

      'email'=>$email,

    ]);
}
```